# Equillogic group manager java error. ExitException: Your security settings have blocked

Tags: java, dell

I want to start our equillogic group manager application to manage our storage. the problem is that when i start it, I get the error: ExitException: Your security settings have blocked an application signed with an expired or noy-yet-valid certificate from running.

I'm using a new admin user account. the original admin account is disabled. on the original admin account it did start.

Comment: Have you added the group manager site to the Java Exception Site List?  Control Panel -> Java Control Panel -> Security Tab -> Edit Site List button

Comment: Yes, I tried to add the site, but it didn't work because I still get the same error.